# How to upgrade rpm package using bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to install the specific rpm packages using bash script. But I am getting error.

I am using the below code :

```
#!/bin/bash

systemctl stop edb-as-10.service 
server_status=$(systemctl status edb-as-10.service|awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'|grep Active|cut -d ":" -f2|cut -d " " -f2|tr -d " ") 
echo "$server_status" 
if [ "$server_status" == inactive ]; then
     echo "You can proceed with upgrading the Potgresql server"
     rpm –Uvh --nodeps edb-as10-server-pltcl-10.9.17-1.rhel7.x86_64.rpm
     systemctl start edb-as-10.service else
     echo " Failed to do Upgrading"
fi
```

I'm getting this error :

> RPM version 4.11.3 Copyright (C) 1998-2002 - Red Hat, Inc. This
>   program may be freely redistributed under the terms of the GNU GPL
>
> Usage: rpm [-aKfgpqVcdLilsiv?] [-a|--all] [-f|--file] [-g|--group]
>   [-p|--package] [--pkgid] [--hdrid] [--triggeredby] [--whatrequires]
>   [--whatprovides]
>           [--nomanifest] [-c|--configfiles] [-d|--docfiles] [-L|--licensefiles] [--dump] [-l|--list] [--queryformat=QUERYFORMAT]
>   [-s|--state] [--nofiledigest]
>           [--nofiles] [--nodeps] [--noscript] [--allfiles] [--allmatches] [--badreloc] [-e|--erase +] [--excludedocs]
>   [--excludepath=] [--force]
>           [-F|--freshen +] [-h|--hash] [--ignorearch] [--ignoreos] [--ignoresize] [-i|--install] [--justdb] [--nodeps]
>   [--nofiledigest]
>           [--nocontexts] [--noorder] [--noscripts] [--notriggers] [--nocollections] [--oldpackage] [--percent] [--prefix=]
>   [--relocate==]
>           [--replacefiles] [--replacepkgs] [--test] [-U|--upgrade +] [--reinstall=+] [-D|--define 'MACRO
>   EXPR'] [--undefine=MACRO]
>           [-E|--eval 'EXPR'] [--macros=] [--noplugins] [--nodigest] [--nosignature] [--rcfile=] [-r|--root ROOT]
>   [--dbpath=DIRECTORY]
>           [--querytags] [--showrc] [--quiet] [-v|--verbose] [--version] [-?|--help] [--usage] [--scripts] [--setperms] [--setugids]
>   [--conflicts] [--obsoletes]
>           [--provides] [--requires] [--info] [--changelog] [--xml] [--triggers] [--last] [--dupes] [--filesbypkg] [--fileclass]
>   [--filecolor] [--fscontext]
>           [--fileprovide] [--filerequire] [--filecaps]

But when I run the command

```
rpm –Uvh --nodeps edb-as10-server-pltcl-10.9.17-1.rhel7.x86_64.rpm
```

on terminal its working but when it placed in script its not working.

Comment: The `–` you're using for the first set of rpm options isn't the correct one, it should be `-` (that often happens when copy-pasting from MS Word which autocorrects `-` to `–`). Voting to close as typo, tell me if that's not the problem or not the only one and I'll retract my vote.

Comment: Not your problem, but btw, `==` isn't guaranteed to work inside `[ ]`; `=` is the only POSIX-standardized string comparison operator to `test`; see the spec @ https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html.

Comment: thanks Aaron , its working . Thanks for your kind support

Comment: i have modified the scripts and added the absolute path its working now. below you can find my code:- 
path='/root/EDB_Patching/EDB_10.9.17/'
echo '$path'
echo "$server_status"
if [ "$server_status" == inactive ]; then
        echo "You can proceed with upgrading the Potgresql server"
        for i in `ls $path`;do
        rpm -Uvh --nodeps $path$i;
        done;
        systemctl start edb-as-10.service
else
        echo " Failed to do Upgrading"
fi